# FlashDevelop Compile settings

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I'm using FlashDevelop (latest version) + Flex 4 SDK for some projects, and am finding it a very efficient setup so far.

However, I have a problem.

Say I create an AS3 project in FlashDevelop, and add AS3 10 classes to it (in 10 .as files), one of them being my main class which will be the principal SWF. As expected, my main class complies to main.swf. But how do I compile the other 9 classes to SWF's as well?

FD only compiles that class which is checked as "always compile". Others are not compiled. Presently, I go the cumbersome route of selecting each file as the "Always Compile" candidate, and then changing the name of the output swf in project properties before firing the build.

Comment: Not sure I understand this. You don't compile a class, you compile the .fla. I don't use the Flex SDK though, I use the Flash IDE to compile.

Answer (score 4):

FlashDevelop projects only support one compile target (i.e. the "Always Compile" document class). If you need multiple compile targets you'll need to create multiple projects or use something like an ant script. Check out [this](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=838) and [this](http://www.blog.elimak.com/2009/07/tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming heavilyinvolved's answer wasn't it, I'm assuming you weren't trying to compile multiple files, rather have unassociated classes compile too.

If these classes were never mentioned (maybe only by string via `getDefinitionByName`), they won't be compiled even though they are in your project tree. Simply import the classes at the beginning of main class file and they should be compiled together with it. They need to be mentioned somewhere so the compiler knows 'ok these are a part of the project too'.

Answer (score 0):

In case nobody's answered correctly, or people come from Google with the same problem; The menu option may also read "Set Document Class", so check for that.